# Kotlin How to create a template application

Tags: android, kotlin, templates

I have to create 2 application with almost the same design. But the backend i mean the way i receive data and i make request to my api is not the same. And there are also minor design such as color or bouton placement...

So i wanted to know if it's possible to create and app template i was thinking of creating a library module such as aar that would hold all the design then i would import it in both my application ?

But if i do that, is there a way to to update the design of the library within the app for exemple i assume that i want to change some color i could do it programmatically, but what happen if i want to change some button position or add rounder corner ? Do i have to provide methodes in my library to handle all those cases ? or is there a way to handle those within the app, meaning that the app could change some design of the library it self ?

In the end would like to have the logic in my app then give all information to the template library to render the design. So i would like to know if there is a way to implement such thing and what are the best practices to do it.

Comment: The standard way is the AAR as u mention. Or just create a module that you copy and import on your project, which will give your way more flexibility in customization without having to rely on a specific API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have in my projects two ways.

**Library**, as you mention. I use it when there are routines that are common to several projects. It is possible to change color patterns and some style details. But it is often plastered.

**Flavors - Build Variants** https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants

With build variants you can create one project/app with two versions, chandind only wat you need. This option is very good when you want to change color, endpoint, style, show or hide some system functionality. I use it and it's very good.